# Windows Aero Forms Errors

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, aero

Okay, so I have followed the docs right down to the smallest detail, and it keeps giving me the following error when I try to debug and run (F5):

> PInvokeStackImbalance was detected
>   Message: A call to PInvoke function
>   'VistaControls!VistaControls.Dwm.NativeMethods::DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea'
>   has unbalanced the stack. This is
>   likely because the managed PInvoke
>   signature does not match the unmanaged
>   target signature. Check that the
>   calling convention and parameters of
>   the PInvoke signature match the target
>   unmanaged signature.

I have no idea what this means, or how to fix it! Can somebody please help? Any suggestions?

I have used this before but it's not working this time. I am using VS2010 Express C# WinForms, .NET 4 (As I was before when I first used it ages ago.)

Thank you

Link: http://windowsformsaero.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Glass%20on%20WinForms&referringTitle=Documentation

And yep, I have noticed the correction a person made down the bottom of that page, and I fixed that up, but it still doesn't work!

The Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using VistaControls.Dwm;

namespace One_Stop_Management
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            e.Graphics.FillRectangles(Brushes.Black, new Rectangle[] {
        new Rectangle(0, 0, this.ClientSize.Width, 30),
        new Rectangle(this.ClientSize.Width - 30, 0, 30, this.ClientSize.Height),
        new Rectangle(0, this.ClientSize.Height - 30, this.ClientSize.Width, 30),
        new Rectangle(0, 0, 30, this.ClientSize.Height)
    });
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);

            VistaControls.Dwm.DwmManager.EnableGlassSheet(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears to be telling you that something is wrong with the P/Invoke definition for the `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` function, but you'll need to post the definition you currently have in order for anyone to tell you have to fix it. My educated guess is that there's an `int` used when an `IntPtr` should have been.

Comment: @Cody Gray; The issue's been solved now, but I'll post my code anyway at the bottom of my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

By reverting to .NET 3.5 you just hid the problem: the stack imbalance is still present, you just don't get any exception from the Managed Debugging Assistant that is responsible for detecting correct P/Invoke calls, for a reason unknown to me.

The signature of `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` in the "Windows Forms Aero" library is wrong.

Here is the original unmanaged signature:

```
HRESULT WINAPI DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(HWND hWnd, __in  const MARGINS *pMarInset);
```

Here is the signature in the library:

```
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
public static extern int DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(IntPtr hWnd, ref Margins pMarInset);
```

While it seems to match the unmanaged one at first sight, it isn't. `PreserveSig = false` tells the CLR to interpret the returned HRESULT and automatically throw an exception if it's corresponding to an error (see [PreserveSig on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.preservesig.aspx)). The function return type must be `void` and not `int` anymore, since the result has already been consumed from the stack by the runtime.

Change to `PreserveSig = true` in the library code and the stack imbalance will be gone.

Comment: PreserveSig = false is not a bad idea here, it automatic generates an exception when the function fails.  But *do* change the return type to "void".  Otherwise make sure to throw the exception yourself.

Comment: You're absolutely right Hans, but the library is already checking for the return value and throwing a custom exception, so PreserveSig = true should suffice here, even if it's generally better to set it to false.

Answer (score -1):

Never mind. I got it. It's such a shame this doesn't work with .NET 4!

You need to go to Project Properties, and change it from .NET Framework 4 to 3.5 or lower*.